XORA Project React Image Not Loading - Not Even Viewable in Console
I'm early on in JSM's https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukiGFmZ32YA which is only React and Tailwind. This is the first image needed in the project, the logo. I've coded it exactly how it is and even checking over JSM's image code:
  return (
    <header>
      <div>
        <a>
          <img src="/images/xora.svg" alt="xora" width={115} height={55} />
        </a>
      </div>
    </header>
  )
}
export default Header


Images are one with no logo and what it's meant to be at this point. Any help would be hugelyyyy appreciated   TY```


[![No Logo][1]][1]

[![with Logo][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/53IPqgnH.png
  [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/cwrdrqZg.png

